# cannot be deleted because deletion protection is enabled -Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer, terraform-modules

I have created ALB through terraform with `enable_deletion_protection = true`

However when I tried deleting it with `enable_deletion_protection = false`

It is not happening and also I have also gone through several other stuff to get the solution. Any Suggestion on this ?

Answer (score 2):

There are two steps involved in this:

First change `enable_deletion_protection = true` to `enable_deletion_protection = false`.
Then run `terraform apply`
This will then allow the resource to be deleted.

Second, run `terraform destroy`

Answer (score 0):

The entire point of `enable_deletion_protection` is to **make it difficult to delete**. You have to change it using AWS Console, or [local-exec](https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec) in Terraform.

Comment: Alright @Marcin However I was thinking there might be a way to make it happen through terraform configuration. Anyway thanks for the help

Comment: @Ak361 Yes, using local-exec you can do it in TF.